# realloc fails in simple dict library

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory, realloc

I wrote a lightweight dictionary for a quick project with C, and I am getting the error: `realloc(): invalid next size`. I know this means my heap is corrupted somehow, but I'm not sure what I did wrong, it seems like my code is super simple.

The realloc always fails the fourth access, ie when `dict->num_kvs = 4`

Below is my code. It includes the dict library as well as the function that is using it. Any help would be much appreciated

Offending function:

```
int* get_letter_frequencies(char* stream) { 

    Dict* dict = Dict_initialize();    

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(stream); i++) {
        Dict_increment_or_add_key(dict, stream[i]);
    }

    int* to_return = Dict_get_values_array(dict);

    Dict_free();

    return to_return;
}
```

simple_dict.c (plus the struct definitions)

```
typedef struct kv_pair {
    char key;
    int value;
} KV_Pair;

typedef struct dict_ {
    struct kv_pair* kv_pairs;
    int num_kvs;
} Dict;

Dict* Dict_initialize() {
    Dict* to_return = malloc(sizeof(Dict));
    to_return->num_kvs = 0;
    to_return->kv_pairs = NULL;
    return to_return;
}

void Dict_free(Dict* dict) {
    free(dict->kv_pairs);
    free(dict);
}

int Dict_add_key(Dict* dict, char key) {
    dict->num_kvs++;
    printf("next size: %d\n", dict->num_kvs);
    dict->kv_pairs = realloc(dict->kv_pairs, dict->num_kvs * sizeof(KV_Pair));
    printf("realloc passed \n");

    dict->kv_pairs[dict->num_kvs].value = 1;

    return 0;
}

int Dict_find_key(Dict* dict, char key){

    for(int i = 0; i < dict->num_kvs; i++) {
        char cur_key = dict->kv_pairs[i].key;
        if(cur_key == key) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

int Dict_increment_or_add_key(Dict* dict, char key) {

    int key_index = Dict_find_key(dict, key);

    if(key_index == -1) {
        Dict_add_key(dict, key);
    } else {
        dict->kv_pairs[key_index].value++;
    }


}

int* Dict_get_values_array (Dict* dict) {
    int* to_return = malloc(dict->num_kvs * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < dict->num_kvs; i++) {
        to_return[i] = dict->kv_pairs[i].value;
    }

    if(dict->num_kvs > 26) {
        printf("more than 26 kvs: %d", dict->num_kvs);
    }

    return to_return;
}
```

Comment: Sad thing with corrupted memory is where the program visibly fails is almost never where the bug is.

Comment: In other words, for others to have a chance of finding the problem you need to provide  complete minimal code that can reproduce the problem. See: [mre]. That is, include the `main` and any other code needed to set up and reproduce the issue.

Comment: `dict->kv_pairs[dict->num_kvs].value = 1;` accesses out of bounds memory. An array allocation of `dict->num_kvs` elements has a max valid index of `dict->num_kvs - 1`.

Comment: I feel silly. Thank you guys so much for the help. That did in fact fix the problem

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(stream); i++) {...}` <<-- you actually wrote this?

Comment: what's wrong with that? ik it's a little insecure for production code, but I know for sure that stream has a null terminator

Comment: With `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(stream); i++)` you're telling the compiler to recompute the length of the string on every iteration. A smart compile will compute once if it can prove that the size will never change, but that proof can be tricky and the compiler might miss out on the opportunity. Also watch out for lengths that exceed the size of `int`. wildplasser might be seeing something I've missed, though. 
`for(char *chp = stream; chp ; chp++) { Dict_increment_or_add_key(dict, *chp); }` will be a bit more predictable, still assuming the size of the string will never shrink.

Comment: oh true, thank you I didn't notice that. I also really like that loop structure, it's definitely the best way to do it if you don't need the index for other purposes

Comment: also, I think you made a small error, I think the second statement in the for loop needs to be `*chp;` , not `chp;`, because we're looking for the character to be 0, not the address

Comment: Yes. Thank you. That's a typo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to add the first element, you are incrementing `dict->num_kvs` to `1`, then you allocate a single element. Then this line:

```
dict->kv_pairs[dict->num_kvs].value = 1;
```

It will try to write to the `[1]` element, instead of `[0]` element. This is out of bounds. You should use:

```
dict->kv_pairs[dict->num_kvs-1].value = 1;
```

**PS:** If you're using GCC or Clang, [AddressSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) is a great tool to help you detect these type of bugs.